# perl symlink immediate target

Tags: perl, symlink-traversal

I am looking for simple & proper way to obtain **absolute path of symlink's immediate target** (not final target), in ***perl***.

My Example Tree:

```
|-- dir1
|   |-- link1 -> ../dir2/link2
|-- dir2
|   `-- link2 -> ../dir3/file.txt
|-- dir3
|   `-- file.txt
`-- test
    `-- script.pl
```

Code1:

```
my $link = dirname($ARGV[0]).'/'.readlink($ARGV[0]); 
print rel2abs($link), "\n";
```

Cmd: `./script.pl ../dir1/link1`

Result: `/tmp/perl_script_test/test/../dir1/../dir2/link2`

Expected: `/tmp/perl_script_test/dir2/link2`

**I am looking for absolute path of symlink's immediate target without `../`**

I tried `abs_path()`, `realpath()` but they all give path to final target (`file.txt`)

Is there any build-in function that does what I want to do I need to split the path and do manual concatenation ?

--

Mohan G

Comment: `Cwd::abs_path` and `Cwd::realpath` are the same sub.

Answer (score 1):

File::Path's `absolute` doesn't do any file system checks.

```
use File::Path qw( file );

my $link_qfn = file(...);

my $link_dir_qfn = $link_qfn->dir;
my $target_qfn   = $link_dir_qfn->file(readlink($link_qfn));
my $target_fqfn  = $target_qfn->absolute;

say $target_fqfn;
```

Say the CWD is `/tmp/perl_script_test/test`

```
$link_qfn     ../dir1/link1
$link_dir_qfn ../dir1
$target_qfn   ../dir1/../dir2/link2
$target_fqfn  /tmp/perl_script_test/test/../dir1/../dir2/link2
```

Say the CWD is `/tmp/perl_script_test`

```
$link_qfn     dir1/link1
$link_dir_qfn dir1
$target_qfn   dir1/../dir2/link2
$target_fqfn  /tmp/perl_script_test/dir1/../dir2/link2
```

---

You've added to the following to your question:

> I am looking for absolute path of symlink's immediate target without ../

You can't safely do that without possibly resolving symlinks. For example,

```
/tmp/perl_script_test/dir1/../dir2/link2
```

is not necessarily equivalent to

```
/tmp/perl_script_test/dir2/link2
```

because

```
/tmp/perl_script_test/dir1
```

could be a symlink.

---

The following might be sufficient for you:

```
use Cwd        qw( real_path );
use File::Path qw( dir file );

my $link_qfn = file(...);

my $link_dir_qfn    = $link_qfn->dir;
my $target_qfn      = $link_dir_qfn->file(readlink($link_qfn));
my $target_fn       = $target_qfn->basename;
my $target_dir_qfn  = $target_qfn->dir;
my $target_dir_fqfn = dir(real_path($target_dir_qfn));
my $target_fqfn     = $target_dir_fqfn->file($target_fn);

say $target_fqfn;
```

Say the CWD is `/tmp/perl_script_test/test`

```
$link_qfn        ../dir1/link1
$link_dir_qfn    ../dir1
$target_qfn      ../dir1/../dir2/link2
$target_fn       link2
$target_dir_qfn  ../dir1/../dir2
$target_dir_fqfn /tmp/perl_script_test/dir2
$target_fqfn     /tmp/perl_script_test/dir2/link2
```

You will only get the above output if none of the following are symlinks:

```
/tmp
/tmp/perl_script_test
/tmp/perl_script_test/test
/tmp/perl_script_test/dir1
/tmp/perl_script_test/dir2
```

(You could make it work even if the first two are symlinks, but that would take even more work.)

Comment: Still I get: `/tmp/perl_script_test/test/../dir2/link2`

Comment: That is what you asked for. Are you complaining that it doesn't produce `/tmp/perl_script_test/dir2/link2`? There's no way to know that without performing file system tests because `/tmp/perl_script_test/test` could be a symlink, and you specifically asked not to resolve any other symlinks.

Comment: You're two criteria (resolving `..` and not resolving symlinks) are incompatible.

Comment: My code was already giving `/tmp/perl_script_test/test/../dir1/../dir2/link2`. I am looking for absolute path without `../`. Sorry deleted by mistake.

Comment: Also your code does not work if I execute the script from `/tmp/perl_script_test/` or `/tmp`. Yes I am looking for absolute path of symlink's immediate target without `../`.

Comment: Fixed the problem identified in the last comment. Could continue to use File::Spec::Functions, but Path::Tiny is a wrapper for File::Spec::Functions that's easier to use.

Comment: Added to answer.